# java matrix chain multiplication array index out of bound exception

Tags: matrix-multiplication, indexoutofboundsexception

```
Trying to do chain matrix multiplication but the code throws an out of bound exception at 2 places, please help me eliminate it.
The exception occurs at 2 places
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at Recursive.Recursive_Matrix(Recursive.java:27)
    at Recursive.main(Recursive.java:15).
```

The problem using the following recursion by repeatedly calling itself as follows:

```
 mij =  0, if   i = j else it is

        min   ( mik + mk+1 j + ri-1 * rk * rj )    if  i < j
             i ≤ k < j
```

I think its related to MAX value being 99999.Or, it would be due to some other comparisons.

```
 class Recursive{


    public static int SIZE = 7;
    public static int MAX = 99999;

    static int M[][] = new int[SIZE][SIZE];
    static int i, k, q, j;
    static int P[] = new int []  { 25,10,15,5,30,10,15};


    public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Recursive_Matrix( 1, SIZE);
        Print_M();

       return;
    }

    static int Recursive_Matrix(int i, int j) 
    {
        if( i == j )
            return 0;
        else
        {
            M[i][j] = MAX;
            for(k = i; k <= j-1; k++)
            {
                q =  Recursive_Matrix(i, k) + Recursive_Matrix( k+1, j) +  ( P[i-1] * P[k] * P[j] );
                if( q < M[i][j])
                    M[i][j] = q;
            }
        }
        return M[i][j]; 
    }
```

//this function is simply used to print the elements of the matrix
//the diagonal elements are all 0, and the other elements are computed from the above recursive function.
        static void Print_M()
        {
            for(int x = 1; x<= SIZE; x++)
            {
                for(int y = 1; y <= SIZE; y++)
                {
                    System.out.println(M[x][y]+"  ");
                }
                System.out.println("\n");
            }
        }
        }

Answer (score 0):

Just have a look at your first call `Recursive_Matrix( 1, SIZE);`. Now `j=7` and later `...M[j]...` and  `...P[j]...` which is out of bound as indexes start with `0`. Use your debugger and step through the code!